# How to configure idleWaitTime Environment Variable in QuartzScheduler for Spring Framework

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, quartz-scheduler, hikaricp

I currently am using a third party application that uses the spring framework and am trying to troubleshoot an issue where something in the spring framework keeps recreating a connection every 30 seconds to a serverless postgres database in AWS. I am using a Hikari datasource that has been configured with the following environment variables:

```
DATASOURCE_MINIMUMIDLE=0
DATASOURCE_IDLETIMEOUT=30000
DATASOURCE_MAXLIFETIME=60000
```

I have confirmed these settings are modifying the hikari pool as expected.

Investigating the issue, I found that Quartz is scheduling a query every 30 seconds or so. I've tried setting the env var to control the idle timeout for the main scheduler loop:

https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/9f9e400733f51f7cb658e3319fc2c140ab8af938/quartz-core/src/main/java/org/quartz/core/QuartzSchedulerThread.java#L244

Either the env var I'm trying to set to control the idleWaitTime is incorrect or something else is going on.

Does anyone have experience controlling the quartz idleWaitTime with the environment variables?

I've tried SPRING_QUARTZ_PROPERTIES_ORG_QUARTZ_SCHEDULER_IDLEWAITTIME, but that does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting the SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON environment variable with the following:
`"{\"spring\":{\"application\":{\"quartz\":{\"org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime\":\"600000\"}}}}"`